# Java: Component.printAll() problem

Tags: java, printing, jframe

I'm trying to print a JFrame using the PrintUtilities Class:

```
package util;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class PrintUtilities implements Printable {
  private Component componentToBePrinted;

  public static void printComponent(Component c) {
    new PrintUtilities(c).print();
  }

  public PrintUtilities(Component componentToBePrinted) {
    this.componentToBePrinted = componentToBePrinted;
  }

  public void print() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(this);
    if (printJob.printDialog())
      try {
        printJob.print();
      } catch(PrinterException pe) {
        System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
      }
  }

  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {
        if (page > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        /* Print the entire visible contents of a java.awt.Frame */
        componentToBePrinted.printAll(g2d);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
  }

  public static void disableDoubleBuffering(Component c) {
    RepaintManager currentManager = RepaintManager.currentManager(c);
    currentManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(false);
  }

  public static void enableDoubleBuffering(Component c) {
    RepaintManager currentManager = RepaintManager.currentManager(c);
    currentManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

Here is the source for the JFrame:
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * NewJFrame.java
 *
 * Created on Jun 24, 2010, 12:24:17 PM
 */

```
package billing.print;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form NewJFrame */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        new util.PrintUtilities(rootPane).print();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addContainerGap(191, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 378, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

This is a screenshot of the JFrame :
http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/1980/48727815.jpg

And this is what the print (xps) came out to be:
http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/9954/47028546.jpg

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get exactly the same result when attempting to print to an .xps, but it does print correctly when I choose to save as to the Microsoft Office Document Image Writer (.tif) or directly to my printer.

Does your target have to be an .xps file or were you just using that for testing?